# Jquery fancybox options don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Here's some of the code, the box displays fine but none of the options seem to affect anything at all!

The popup HTML:

```
<div id="fb-pop">
    <div id="fb-content">
        <div class="fb-txt">
            <strong>Have you considered buying a license for Construct 2?</strong><br /><br />
            It comes with more lots more features and possibilities.  Make better games!<br />
            <span class="ti">(And no more annoying messages!)</span>
        </div>
        <a class="get" href="REPLACEME" title="Your support is appreciated!"></a><br />
        <a class="no-thx" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$.fancybox.close()" title="Are you sure?  Upgrading your license helps support Construct 2's development!">No thanks, maybe next time!</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#fb-content" id="autostart"></a>
```

The JS at the bottom of the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $("a#autostart").fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 600,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'overlayShow': false
    });

    $("a#autostart").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

No matter what options/properties I put in the javascript NOTHING seems to change!  It still behaves in exactly the same way in all browsers.

I'm trying to make it so that the background overlay will not close the fancybox when it is clicked (so the user has to either click the X or the close link).

Comment: `$("#autostart")` should work just fine as a selector.

Comment: @Hogan I changed the selector.  The problem is it all works fine, but if I change the properties/options the box still behaves exactly the same.  The options seem to have absolutely no effect on the fancybox.

Comment: oh, I did not think that would fix it, just pointing out that if you have an id you don't need anything else and it will probably make it slower not faster..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure it's not:

```
$("a#autostart").trigger('click');
```

instead of :

```
$("a#autostart").fancybox().trigger('click');
```